# How to get Product name in custom module in magento grid view?

Tags: php, magento

I have `product id`. database field name `productid` in custom module

I want to show product name on custom module list view.

Here is my code:

```
protected function _prepareColumns() {         
    $this->addColumn('productid', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('productpdf')->__('productid'),
        'align'     => 'center',
        'index'     => 'productid',
    ));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For this You have to separately create the collection(or in your existing collection include the below query) for get product name from product id..

You can do like this

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('name');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('productid');
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{


       $this->addColumn('productid', array(
       'header' => Mage::helper('productpdf')->__('productid'),
      'align'     =>'center',
     'index'     =>'productid',


      ));


         $this->addColumn('name', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('productpdf')->__('Name'),
        'width'     => '150',
        'index'     => 'name'
    ));


}
```

In **addAttributeToFilter('productid')** you have to pass your product id.
Hope this work:-)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using too much bunch of code, add below code in your model/productpdf.php file.

```
  /**
 * @param int $productId.
 * @return product name.
 */
public function getProductNameById($productId)
{
    $query_select = "SELECT value FROM `".Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix()."catalog_product_entity_varchar` WHERE
            entity_id = '".$productId."' AND `attribute_id` = 71";

    return $data = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read')->fetchAll($query_select); 

}
```

Now just call this function in your file.

```
  $productNameArray = Mage::getModel('productpdf/productpdf')->getProductNameById($productId);
```

Add new column for display product name

```
  $this->addColumn('name', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('productpdf')->__('Name'),
    'width'     => '150',
    'index'     =>  $productNameArray[0]['value']
));
```

Cheers!!